# Что значит «на полукегельную»?

Tags: на-полукегельную

«Грамота.ру» пишет, что знаки номера и процента отбиваются от цифр «на полукегельную». Что значит «на полукегельную»? [image: на полукегельную]

Comment: Быстрый ответ. Понятие кегль шрифта можно охарактеризовать как размер строки, в котором расположена буква. В него входят все выносные элементы, заплечики и высота самого высокого знака.
Сказав более простым и понятным языком для обывателей кегель – это размер шрифта, некая мера роста. Измерение его происходит в типографских пунктах. Если переводить их в миллиметры по системе Дида то получится 1 ПТ = 0.3759 мм.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кегль